# DataContract definition on generic classes

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, dto

We have a layered application:

**UI <--> WCF <--> DAL** (Using entity framework)

We don't want to expose our EntityTypes, so we are converting to custom DTOs in the DAL. 
The DTO types are referenced by the UI, WCF and DAL solutions.

A couple of questions have been raised -

- Are there any negative implications of adding the [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes to all of our Custom DTO types and properties?
- Might this cause any problems in applications that don't want to access the data via WCF?

Comment: Why are you using WCF in between your UI and DAL?

Comment: We have to process a bunch of business logic. The full stack of layers would be: UI -> WCF -> BL -> DAL -> DB.

Comment: So my question is why introduce the WCF layer at all. Is the UI hosted away from the business layer?

Comment: Yes, they can be installed in different locations, they are also consumed by more than one application.

Answer (score 2):

No and No. These attributes are part of the mechanism WCF uses to create and enforce your webservice contract and determine what gets serialized over the wire or not.

Comment: Well technically those attributes are used by the DataContractSerializer, which is used by WCF.  However, you do not need to use WCF to use serialization.

Comment: If you expose a wsdl from a WCF service, the datacontract and datamember attributes will affect the outputted schema. So the outputs of those attributes are relevant to non-wcf consumers also - if they are depending on the wsdl to generate a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are inserted into the metadata and reside there until some user code queries them using reflection. They don't have any performance implications, the only thing is that they enlarge the assembly metadata tables.
But it's more of a design issue, you normally shouldn't have fallen into this scenario. If you decorate some class with a platform-agnostic attribute, such as `[Serializable]`, then you'd say "OK, this type might be serialized one day, no matter how and where you want to use it". And that's pretty much OK, but if you decorate the same class with a platform-specific attribute like the `[DataContract]`, then you're kinda telling the world that "OK, this is a WCF DTO and is intended to be used in operation contracts". Plus you're coupling the class with the DataContractSerializer and even more, if you use `DataContract` then you have to explicitly define `[DataMember]`s as well.

Conclusion - you normally shouldn't have gone this way. Think about refactoring your software model.